# using c++ const on user-entered data?

Tags: c++, constants

Suppose that I wanted to read an integer from cin and then make it immutable. I can do:

```
int a;
cin >> a;
const int b = a;
```

Then, I would have a variable (b) which is initialized to user data, but cannot be changed. However, I think I'm abusing the const keyword here. Is this an acceptable thing to do? The compiler seems to be okay with it, but I'm just wondering if it's right from a stylistic point of view.

Comment: yup. that's what the keyword is for. This is not just acceptable, it's an application of a language feature. Why were you worried?

Comment: Nothing particularly wrong with it, but I'd say that it's pretty pointless, considered that `b` isn't a constant known at compile time, is local and is just an `int`.

Comment: This is good.  when you start typing volatile that's when you need "Check Yourself Before...."

Comment: @Matteo, it's not pointless. I'd even say it *wise* to mark variables const when you don't intend for them to change. That way, if you accidentally attempt to misuse them, the compiler will catch you and prevent it. Otherwise, you'll only notice your mistake after you compile, run, and test your program and notice that something went wrong. The easiest debugging is the debugging you don't have to do because there was never a bug in the first place.

Comment: The only place I would find this practice dangerous are embedded systems, where some compilers tend to let the precompiler run blindly through `const`s as if they were `#define`s.

Comment: @RobKennedy: I know the importance of `const` correctness, I'm just saying that for a "little local `int`" (very limited scope => it's much simpler to avoid those mistakes, since the code that works on it is all here; just an `int` => no surprises for `const`/non-`const` methods & co.) I find it a bit excessive to create a separate variable just to add constness. On the other hand, it surely costs about nothing and adds a little extra security, so go ahead with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's completely fine. You're free to create const variables from non-const data, even user-entered data.

You might even write a function so you don't have the stray `a` variable sitting around afterward. For example:

```
int read_int(std::istream& in) {
  int a;
  in >> a;
  return a;
}

int const b = read_int(std::cin);
```

Comment: Using a [GNU language extension](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/gnuexts.html#SEC63) you could do `const int b = ({ int a; std::cin >> a; a; });` (of course in C++0x you have lambdas: `const int c = []() -> int { int a; std::cin >> a; return a; }();`

Answer (score 2):

This is a philosophical question. :)

In my opinion you are not doing any stylistic aberration. You are defined a variable that **from that point** do not change anymore. The history of that variable value is negligible. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's fine.  You are assured that the value of 'b' will never change, within the context of the running program.

Answer (score 0):

Though I agree with Rob & David, IMO it's better to make `b` a reference when possible:

```
int a;
cin >> a;
const int &b = a;
```

Though in case of int you may not save much, in case of bigger objects you'll save copy c'tor call and the memory.